# How to get container name from file URL in Azure Blob Storage C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

We are able to get container name using the code below:

```
new CloudBlobContainer(url).Name
```

But this method works only if the URL is container base URL.

If we are trying to pass the URL of a file and try to get the container name, the code will not return data as expected. In this case, we have to use the CloudBlockBlob object.

```
new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(Url)).Container.Name
```

Is there any method to get a container name that will work for URLs listed below:

```
http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/10d59357-b4d1-41e8-ba2a-d92964e1ac53

http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/10d59357-b4d1-41e8-ba2a-d92964e1ac53/temp/1.txt
```

Answer (score 14):

**Older SDK (9.3.3)**

If you're using older SDK (9.3.3), You can use `BlobClient` and the name of the blob container will be available in `BlobContainerName` property.

```
BlobClient client = new BlobClient(new Uri(url));
```

[image]

---

[image]

**Newer SDK (12.2.0)**

For newer SDK (12.2.0), you can use `BlobUriBuilder` and the name of the blob container will be available in `BlobContainerName` property.

```
BlobUriBuilder blobUriBuilder = new BlobUriBuilder(new Uri(url));
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Hi Gaurav, Thanks for your input this works as expected. Do you have any similar method available for Azure Blob Storage SDK v11